# ELF Binary Error Unix ("./X No such file or directory")

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a 3.4 Kernel Linux Virtual Machine and I want to run a compiled ELF Binary.

```
bash-4.3# file insane 
insane: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=0d449c7f73019c2ac7708f6bd0b21558da139135, stripped
```

I have compiled it on Ubuntu 32 Bit and now I want to run it on an Unix i386 virtual machine with Linux Kernel 3.4.0
ldd on the Unix image where it's not working:

```
bash-4.3# ldd insane 
insane:
        -lc.6 => not found
```

ldd on the Ubuntu 32bit where I compiled the binary and works:

```
ldd insane
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7784000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb75b5000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x80086000)
```

Those are my libraries:

```
bash-4.3# ls /usr/lib/
bc                                      liblua.so
cawf                                    liblua.so.5
crontab                                 liblua.so.5.3
crt0.o                                  liblua_pic.a
crtbegin.o                              liblutok.a
crtbeginS.o                             liblutok.so
crtbeginT.o                             liblutok.so.2
crtend.o                                liblutok.so.2.0
crtendS.o                               liblutok_pic.a
crti.o                                  liblwip.a
crtn.o                                  liblwip_pic.a
fonts                                   liblzma.a
gcrt0.o                                 liblzma.so
keymaps                                 liblzma.so.2
libarchive.a                            liblzma.so.2.0
libarchive.so                           liblzma_pic.a
libarchive.so.3                         libm.a
libarchive.so.3.1                       libm.so
libarchive_pic.a                        libm.so.0
libasyn.a                               libm.so.0.11
libasyn_pic.a                           libm387.a
libatf-c++.a                            libm387.so
libatf-c++.so                           libm387.so.0
libatf-c++.so.1                         libm387.so.0.1
libatf-c++.so.1.0                       libm387_pic.a
libatf-c++_pic.a                        libm_pic.a
libatf-c.a                              libmagic.a
libatf-c.so                             libmagic.so
libatf-c.so.0                           libmagic.so.5
libatf-c.so.0.0                         libmagic.so.5.1
libatf-c_pic.a                          libmagic_pic.a
libaudiodriver.a                        libmenu.a
libaudiodriver_pic.a                    libmenu.so
libbdev.a                               libmenu.so.6
libbdev_pic.a                           libmenu.so.6.0
libbfd.so.13                            libmenu_pic.a
libbfd.so.13.0                          libminc.a
libblacklist.a                          libminixfs.a
libblacklist.so                         libminixfs_pic.a
libblacklist.so.0                       libmj.a
libblacklist.so.0.0                     libmj.so
libblacklist_pic.a                      libmj.so.1
libblockdriver.a                        libmj.so.1.0
libblockdriver_pic.a                    libmj_pic.a
libbz2.a                                libmthread.a
libbz2.so                               libmthread.so
libbz2.so.1                             libmthread.so.0
libbz2.so.1.1                           libmthread.so.0.0
libbz2_pic.a                            libmthread_pic.a
libc++.a                                libnetdriver.a
libc++.so                               libnetdriver_pic.a
libc++.so.1                             libnetpgp.a
libc++.so.1.0                           libnetpgp.so
libc++_pic.a                            libnetpgp.so.3
libc.a                                  libnetpgp.so.3.0
libc.so                                 libnetpgp_pic.a
libc.so.12                              libnetpgpverify.a
libc.so.12.197                          libnetpgpverify.so
libc_pic.a                              libnetpgpverify.so.4
libchardriver.a                         libnetpgpverify.so.4.0
libchardriver_pic.a                     libnetpgpverify_pic.a
libcrypt.a                              libnetsock.a
libcrypt.so                             libnetsock_pic.a
libcrypt.so.1                           libopcodes.so.6
libcrypt.so.1.0                         libopcodes.so.6.0
libcrypt_pic.a                          libpci.a
libcrypto.a                             libpci.so
libcrypto.so                            libpci.so.2
libcrypto.so.8                          libpci.so.2.1
libcrypto.so.8.4                        libpci_pic.a
libcrypto_pic.a                         libprop.a
libcurses.a                             libprop.so
libcurses.so                            libprop.so.1
libcurses.so.7                          libprop.so.1.1
libcurses.so.7.0                        libprop_pic.a
libcurses_pic.a                         libpuffs.a
libddekit.a                             libpuffs.so
libddekit_pic.a                         libpuffs.so.2
libddekit_usb_client.a                  libpuffs.so.2.0
libddekit_usb_client_pic.a              libpuffs_pic.a
libddekit_usb_server.a                  librefuse.a
libddekit_usb_server_pic.a              librefuse.so
libdes.a                                librefuse.so.2
libdes.so                               librefuse.so.2.0
libdes.so.8                             librefuse_pic.a
libdes.so.8.2                           librmt.a
libdes_pic.a                            libsaslc.a
libdevman.a                             libsaslc.so
libdevman_pic.a                         libsaslc.so.0
libedit.a                               libsaslc.so.0.0
libedit.so                              libsaslc_pic.a
libedit.so.3                            libsffs.a
libedit.so.3.1                          libsffs_pic.a
libedit_pic.a                           libsqlite3.a
libelf.a                                libsqlite3.so
libelf.so                               libsqlite3.so.1
libelf.so.1                             libsqlite3.so.1.2
libelf.so.1.0                           libsqlite3_pic.a
libelf_pic.a                            libssl.a
libevent.a                              libssl.so
libevent.so                             libssl.so.10
libevent.so.4                           libssl.so.10.5
libevent.so.4.0                         libssl_pic.a
libevent_openssl.a                      libsys.a
libevent_openssl.so                     libsys.so
libevent_openssl.so.4                   libsys.so.0
libevent_openssl.so.4.0                 libsys.so.0.0
libevent_openssl_pic.a                  libsys_pic.a
libevent_pic.a                          libtermcap.a
libexec.a                               libtermcap.so
libexec_pic.a                           libtermcap.so.0
libexecinfo.a                           libtermcap.so.0.6
libexecinfo.so                          libtermcap_pic.a
libexecinfo.so.0                        libterminfo.a
libexecinfo.so.0.0                      libterminfo.so
libexecinfo_pic.a                       libterminfo.so.1
libexpat.a                              libterminfo.so.1.0
libexpat.so                             libterminfo_pic.a
libexpat.so.2                           libtermlib.a
libexpat.so.2.1                         libtermlib.so
libexpat_pic.a                          libtermlib.so.0
libfetch.a                              libtermlib.so.0.6
libfetch.so                             libtermlib_pic.a
libfetch.so.3                           libtimers.a
libfetch.so.3.0                         libtimers_pic.a
libfetch_pic.a                          libusb.a
libfl.a                                 libusb_pic.a
libform.a                               libutil.a
libform.so                              libutil.so
libform.so.6                            libutil.so.7
libform.so.6.0                          libutil.so.7.23
libform_pic.a                           libutil_pic.a
libfsdriver.a                           libvassert.a
libfsdriver_pic.a                       libvboxfs.a
libgcc_s.a                              libvboxfs_pic.a
libgcc_s.so                             libvirtio.a
libgcc_s.so.1                           libvirtio_pic.a
libgcc_s.so.1.0                         libvtreefs.a
libhgfs.a                               libvtreefs_pic.a
libhgfs_pic.a                           libz.a
libinputdriver.a                        libz.so
libinputdriver_pic.a                    libz.so.1
libkvm.a                                libz.so.1.0
libkvm.so                               libz_pic.a
libkvm.so.6                             lua
libkvm.so.6.0                           pkgconfig
libkvm_pic.a                            pwdauth
libl.a                                  security
liblua.a
```

But when I try to run it I get:

```
bash-4.3# ./insane 
bash: ./insane: No such file or directory
```

Comment: this message happens when the file doesn't exist, not because a .so is missing.

Comment: Have you tried copying the missing libc.so.6 and running it with LD_LIBRARY_PATH set appropriately?

Comment: What happens if you try `/lib/ld-linux.so.2 full/insane/path`?

Comment: I tried to copy from the working machine the ld-linux.so.2 into /lib/ folder of the faulty one. After that it's giving me segmentation fault when I try to run it.
[1]   Segmentation fault      ./insane

Comment: @MIND - if `glibc` on the target node is newer and backward compatible with the old node (usually the case), all you need is to create a softlink for both `ld-linux.so` and `libc.so.6`.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the dynamic loader `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` (as identified by `file`).

The error message is pretty confusing, and can be quickly reproduced by modifying the loader location in the header with a hex editor (just search for `ld-linux` and overwrite it with garbage):

```
$ file myfile
myfile: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, 
        version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, 
        interpreter /doesntexistfoobarbaz_.so.2,
        for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, (...)

$ [ -x ./myfile ] && ./myfile
bash: ./myfile: No such file or directory
```

You can run it by putting the correct loader in the correct place, or using another loader explicitly:

```
$ /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ./myfile
Hello World
```

Comment: I copied the ld-linux.so.2 from the working machine to the faulty one and now it's giving me segmentation fault.
If i run bash-4.3$ /lib/ld-linux.so.2 insane it's not showing anything.

Comment: Are the rest of the libraries from the Ubuntu installation? You generally can't compile against one version and run with another.

Comment: I tried just now to copy the /lib/i386-linux-gnu/* to /lib/ on the faulty machine and it's still empty output. ldd shows lc.6 is not found.